# issues with btrfs with read-only mode

Tags: 20.04, btrfs

I have following issue,
when I have installed ubuntu with btrfs I have every couple of days issue that disk is in read-only mode.
When I restart my computer everything is fine until next couple of days.
I installed ubuntu with ext4 and I don't see such issues.

I digged into the partition and founded that maybe I have issue that partition system I have not GPT but MBR.
Is it possible that btrfs cannot work with MBR ?

Comment: I've used BTRFS on a MBR/legacy/DOS partition for ~two years without file-system problems (*excluding disk space issues because of snapshot issues that had me disable the snapshots - or the reason I'd selected BTRFS in the first place.. once snapshots were disabled my issues were gone but that was disk space, not related to RO or partition table*).  I experienced no issues with a MBR partition table.

Comment: thanks for that, I wasn't aware that this can be an issue, I had snapshots created on the same hard-drive, maybe I should have snapshots on a separate drive ?

Comment: I would think the snapshots on the same drive would be far less hassle; but of course the minimum disk space required for Ubuntu does **not** include snapshots/backups, so you need to allocate for that. I realized my disk was too small but it was a small SSD & I gave it a shot; then disabled snapshots as I stated & I didn't try storing them elsewhere so can't comment on that (*I didn't want to need be connected to a network to boot, or connect external drive* etc)

Comment: hmm I see that You have a good idea - have to try it, to create separate partition for snapshots - maybe this will solve my issue.